# How to identify connected blobs with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

I would like to know if there is a parameter or another algorithm to separate and identify connected blobs, like the one pointed in the image.

Comment: You will need to specify what is `blob` and what is `connected`. You are also welcome to post here what exactly have you tried to solve your issue.

Comment: See [ask] and especially [mcve].

Comment: `cv2.connectedComponents()` and/or `cv2.findContours()`